# ActivityTest crashes when there are Dialogs in Activity

Tags: android, testing, android-activity

As the title says, my activity test cases crash with

```
Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException'
```

when there are dialogs respawned in my Activity. All the test runs fine on my Sky A820L but all start to go wrong when I test on Samsung Galaxy S3. I googled around and see some people suggest to use handler to handle the dialog but I can't change the source code of the application. So is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks in advanced!

Edit 1:
There are several places the code use dialog (because this app loads its data from the server so whenever it loads, it pop-up a progress dialog to wait for the data). Therefore, everytime the activities starts to test it starts and stops continuously (for each test case, the activity will start again). I saw the issues was posted here: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14616
but there is no solution to this.
The application code is here:

```
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    this.dialog = new ProgressDialog( this );
    this.dialog.setMessage( "Sending data, please wait..." );
    //something else
 }

 protected void onRequestData()
{
    this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show( this, "", "Loading, please wait...", true, true  );
 }
```

As you can see, everytime the activity starts, it create a new dialog, and there are methods inside that call for the dialog because it has to request data again. Sometimes it runs fine without any problems but most of the time it will fire the error.

Comment: You mean my Activity Test Code? I will post it on Monday because I can't get my code right now.